# Pybind11 function call blocking main thread

Tags: python, c++, python-multithreading, gil, pybind11

I'm using pybind11 to expose [this game code](https://github.com/MatheusZickuhr/Contra_remake) (written in c++) to python.

The first thing I'm trying to do is, basicly start the game by exposing a start function in the c++ part. So far is looking like this (c++):

```c
#define NOMINMAX

#include "GameWinMain.h"
#include "GameEngine.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "Contra.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

using namespace  std;

#define GAME_ENGINE (GameEngine::GetSingleton())

int start()
{
    // Enable run-time memory leak check for debug builds.
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif
    WinMain(GetModuleHandle(0), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);

    return 0;
}

int _tmain()
{
    start();
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    if (GAME_ENGINE == NULL) return FALSE; // create the game engine and exit if it fails
    GAME_ENGINE->SetGame(new Contra()); // any class that implements AbstractGame
    cout << "jogo foi iniciado?";
    return GAME_ENGINE->Run(hInstance, iCmdShow); // run the game engine and return the result
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(contra, m)
{
    cout << "modulo importado! ";
    m.doc() = "contra game";
    m.def("start", &start, "starts the contra game");
}
```

And in the python side is looking like this:

```py
from threading import Thread
from Contra_remake import contra

Thread(target=contra.start, args=()).start()

print('print!')
```

The problem is, the print line is only executed when the game closes, even starting the game in another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is beacuse of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) of Python. You can read more about it [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

If you want to fix the issue, you should release the GIL manually in your C++ code, as described in [this link](https://thomasnyberg.com/releasing_the_gil.html).

In short, you can change your start method like below to avoid your Python thread to be blocked:

```
#include <python.h>

class GilManager
{
public:
   GilManager()
   {
      mThreadState = PyEval_SaveThread();
   }

   ~GilManager()
   {
      if (mThreadState)
         PyEval_RestoreThread(mThreadState);
   }

   GilManager(const GilManager&) = delete;
   GilManager& operator=(const GilManager&) = delete;
private:
   PyThreadState* mThreadState;
};

int start()
{
   GilManager g;
    // Enable run-time memory leak check for debug builds.
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif
    WinMain(GetModuleHandle(0), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @MatheusZickuhr Always say "Thanks" in stackoverflow using upvotes ;-)